# 'Device or resource busy' error thrown when trying to record audio using arecord

Tags: audio, alsa, recording

I'm trying to record audio that is being played on separate channels using `arecord`. I do this by executing the following command in separate threads in a python script:

```
arecord -D plug:"+str(in_id)+" -c 1 -d "+str(duration)+" -f S16_LE -r "+str(rate)+" "+rec_filename
```

where `in_id` is the input channel variable that I pass to each of the threads. But then, the following error is thrown:

```
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:606:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
arecord: main:722: audio open error: Device or resource busy
```

When I run `lsof /dev/snd/pcm*` right before I start recording using `arecord` in my record function in the program, I see the following:

```
COMMAND   PID        USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
aplay   12236       user4  mem    CHR  116,3           493 /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
aplay   12236       user4    4u   CHR  116,3      0t0  493 /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
```

My device definition for input channels in `.asoundrc` is as follows:

```
pcm.!default {
    type plug
    slave {
       pcm "hw:1,0"
    }
}

ctl.!default { 
    type hw
    card 1
}

pcm_slave.usb_audio_1 {
    pcm "hw:1,0"
    channels 8
    rate 44100
    buffer_size 4096
    period_size 1024
}

pcm.outch<num> {
    type dshare
    ipc_key <id>
    slave usb_audio_1
    bindings [ <ch_num> ]
    hint.description "USB output/playback channel <num> (from output port <num>)"
}

pcm.inch<num> {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key <id>
    slave usb_audio_1
    bindings [ <ch_num> ]
    hint.description "USB input/capture channel <num> (from input port <num>)"
}
```

where `<num>` takes all values between 1 and 8 and `<ch_num>` takes all values between 0 and 7.

Since, the error clearly says there is a definite problem with `dsnoop`, does that mean that it is not meant for simultaneous/multi-channel recording? I mean is there a conflict between `dsnoop` and `dshare` or if `dsnoop` can record/capture from only one channel at a time? Is there another way I can achieve this?

Comment: Does a single such `arecord` call work on the command line?

Comment: Yes, single `arecord` call works fine. I can combine `arecord` with `aplay` on pipes as well.

Comment: Does the first `arecord` call from Python work?

Comment: The very first call itself the above error is observed. I mean at the very instant when those threads are created for recording.

Comment: "Busy" means that the device is already open. What is the output of `lsof /dev/snd/pcm*`?

Comment: After the execution of the program, `lsof /dev/snd/pcm*` returns nothing.

Comment: To be sure, run it from your Python program, just before `arecord`.

Comment: I have updated my post with the result of `lsof /dev/snd/pcm*` during the execution of the program.

Comment: What are the `ipc_key` values?

Comment: All the output channels are defined with ipc_key values as 1111,1112,1113...1118 and output channels are defined with ipc_key value as 2111,2112,2113...2118.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ipc_key` is used for communication between the programs that share the same device. This means that you have to use different values for different hardware devices, but that all virtual devices that access the same hardware device (i.e., the same slave `usb_audio_1`) must use the same ID.

Comment: Not even in my wildest dreams I had suspected `ipc_key` to be the cause of this! Obviously, my understanding was flawed. Thanks a lot @CL. for clearing it. Just out of curiosity, in my case, can I put the `ipc_key` in some other container definition block in order to avoid such mistakes. I mean it is only logical to have a master block in the hierarchy with a common field like `ipc_key` right?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the device is being blocked for `arecord` usage if I have VLC open (even if idle and with empty playlist).

Similarly, it is also blocked if I only have the (top-right corner-menu) settings open – presumably because of its sound / mic-test panel.